# Why is this that-clause unnatural as the subject in this sentence?

Tags: relative-clauses, subjects, that

> (1)After the surprising Algiers Agreement between Iran and Iraq is reached, **the United States stops its support for the Kurdish rebels**, *which* causes the fragmentation of the opposition and an increased vulnerability to Hussein's renewed attacks.

> (2)*That* **the United States stops its support for the Kurdish rebels** causes the fragmentation of the opposition and an increased vulnerability to Hussein's renewed attacks.

> (3)It causes the fragmentation of the opposition and an increased vulnerability to Hussein's renewed attacks *that* **the United States stops its support for the Kurdish rebels**

Why are both (2) and (3) unnatural, while (1) is natural?

In PEU Swan writes *which* can refer not only to a noun, but also to the whole of a previous clause,
in this case, **the United States stops its support for the Kurdish rebels**.

He also writes, in another place, a that-clause can be the subject.

So, there should be no problem with (2) or (3).

Answer (score 2):

There is nothing wrong with using a that-clause as the subject of this sentence. The problem is with your use of the simple present tense, which is certainly possible but seems unusual here due to how we would usually expect these events to be reported. (That also makes sentence 1 seem a bit unnatural to me.) Consider this version of your second sentence:

> That the United States is stopping its support for the Kurdish rebels has caused the fragmentation of the opposition and an increased vulnerability to Hussein's renewed attacks.

Voila! Now it's fine.

Comment: Is there a reason for using "has caused" instead of "is causing"? Or "is stopping" instead of "has stopped"?

Comment: If the sentence is now fine, then *it*-extraposition would work, but it doesn’t: *\* It has caused the fragmentation of the opposition ... that the United States is stopping its support for the Kurdish rebels.*

Comment: @alphabet No, I just chose some verb forms that seemed to make sense. Others could work, too.

Comment: @TinfoilHat Are you suggesting that it-extraposition must be possible in order for a sentence beginning with a that-clause to be valid? I would not agree with that.

Comment: Well, no, I guess not.

Comment: But now I see that OP’s (1) uses the narrative present, which is fine. To put it in the past: *After the Algiers Agreement **was** reached, the US **stopped** its support for the rebels, which **caused** fragmentation.* That’s fine. Here’s (2) in the past (not changing the meaning like your verbs do): *That the US **stopped** its support for the rebels **caused**  fragmentation.* If you buy that, then the narrative present is correct too: *That the US **stops** its support for the rebels **causes** fragmentation.* But as @alphabet said, these are all “quite infelicitous” for some reason.

Comment: @TinfoilHat I have a theory: the historical present affects both time (moving the past to the present) and aspect (allowing the simple present instead of the present progressive). I suspect that the change in *time* also affects subordinate clauses, but that the change in aspect *doesn't.* That would explain why the subordinate clause can be in the present progressive but cannot be in the *simple present.*

Comment: @TinfoilHat I have a theory: the historical present affects both time (moving the past to the present) and aspect (allowing the simple present instead of the present progressive). I suspect that the change in *time* also affects subordinate clauses, but that the change in aspect *doesn't.* That would explain why the subordinate clause can be in the present progressive but cannot be in the *simple present.*

Comment: @alphabet — I don’t think it’s the tense or aspect; don’t all these work? *[The fact] that he suggested pie caused rage. [The fact] that he suggests pie causes rage. [The fact] that he is suggesting pie has caused rage.*

Comment: @TinfoilHat Yes, I wrote that the simple present was "certainly possible" because I don't see any error with that sentence due to grammar. If it were an ongoing, habitual action, then I think that simple present would be appropriate. For example: "That the United States stops its support for the Kurdish rebels every five years always causes the fragmentation . . ." That doesn't seem to make much sense logically, though.

Comment: @TinfoilHat Except for sounding somewhat uncommon (I think we'd more often use a different construction), your version with the simple past tense (". . . stopped . . . caused . . .") seems OK to me. I suppose that opinions will differ.

Comment: @TinfoilHat "[The fact] that he is suggesting pie **is causing** rage" sounds better to me, albeit semantically off.

Comment: @TinfoilHat et al.  I think the biggest problem all round is the awkward coordination functioning as the DO of *caused*. The noun *fragmentation* represents a physical event whereas *an increased vulnerability ...* is an abstract relationship. It's a bit like saying *This caused a riot and embarrassment.* The following seems to work much better: "That the United States is stopping its support for the Kurdish rebels has caused the fragmentation of the opposition and and made them increasingly vulnerable to Hussein's renewed attacks." Both clauses there have the same content clause as subject.

Comment: @Araucaria-Nothereanymore. — That’s a good fix. But the whole thing still seems off. It’s not *[the fact] that the US stopped its support* that caused anything; it’s the *US’s stopping support* that caused chaos. Still, I can’t say how that is different than *[The fact] that he suggested pie caused rage.*

Comment: I mostly agree with @TinfoilHat on this one. "That the United States is stopping its support for the Kurdish rebels has caused the fragmentation of the opposition" on its own seems no better to me.

Comment: I think it may partly just be that having a long, non-extraposed *that-*clause at the start of a sentence is awkward and unexpected, particularly when that clause has any level of internal syntactic complexity.

Answer (score 0):

While *some* verbs can take a that-clause as a (usually extraposed) subject, most verbs cannot. The verb *cause* does not allow such a subject.

**Edit:** Auracaria provides this counterexample:

> That you could even suggest such a thing causes the hairs on the back of my neck to bristle with rage.

I'd delete this answer but the comment thread is worth preserving.

Comment: And _cause_ doesn't govern the rule of Extraposition, which would provide the dummy _it_ of (3) if it could apply. But it can't.

Comment: I have no problem with ***It worries me** that the United States **is stopping** its support for the Kurdish rebels* (where I suspect it's syntactically irrelevant to OP that I can't abide Simple Present ***stops***). And I can't see any reason why I shouldn't reword that to [***It causes me distress** that](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22it+causes+me+distress+that%22) the US is doing this,* which looks syntactically close enough to OP's example #3 for me.

Comment: @FumbleFingers **it worries me** can be rephrased as **it is worrisome to me**, and **it causes me distress** as **it is distressful**. They are about impressions. Then, am I right in thinking that *that*-clause can't be the subject of a sentence describing an action.

Comment: So, what kinds of verbs can take a that-clause as a (usually extraposed) subject?

Comment: It seems different people have different ideas about "acceptable" extraposed "that-clauses". Whilst I find your examples a bit clumsy, they seem perfectly grammatical to me. I don't see any reason to say the construction works with ***is***, but not with ***causes***.  But by far the worst aspect of all your examples to me is Simple Present ***stops*** and ***causes***, where I would use ***is stopping, is causing.***

Comment: This is just not true. That you could even suggest such a thing causes the hairs on the back of my neck to bristle with rage.

Comment: @Araucaria-Nothereanymore. Good one. So why does it work there, but not in the OP's example? Is that just an exception to the general rule?

Comment: @Araucaria-Nothereanymore. Good catch. I've edited my answer to note the error; I won't delete it since the comment thread is likely worth preserving.

Comment: @Araucaria-Nothereanymore. Your example sounds perfectly fine to me, whereas OP's (2) is an odd thing to say. I guess it's not about whether you can use a particular verb (e.g., **_cause_**), but about what exactly the whole verb phrase really means.

Comment: @Araucaria-Nothereanymore. In your example, the VP _causes the hairs on the back of my neck to bristle with rage_ basically means "enrages me", which can easily use a _that_-clause as its subject. In OP's (2), on the other hand, the VP _causes the fragmentation of the opposition and an increased vulnerability to Hussein's renewed attacks_ means "fragments the opposition and increases vulnerability to Hussein's renewed attacks", which can hardly use a _that_-clause as its subject.

Comment: @JK2 I think MarcInManhattan's answer--that this is a tense/aspect issue--seems *likely* to be correct, but I'm not 100% convinced, since even his corrected version sounds quite infelicitous.

Comment: @alphabet Agreed. If you edit your answer not to focus on the verb itself but on the meaning of the VP, I think it would be a better answer.

Comment: **Verbs** that take *that*-clause “objects” can only have the *that-clause* in the subject position in the passive voice. Active: *They have acknowledged that you’re a cat.* Passive: *That you’re a cat has been acknowledged [by them].* Passive extraposed *it*: *It has been acknowledged [by them] that you’re a cat.*

Comment: @JK2 Perhaps see my comment to tfh under post above.

Comment: @Araucaria-Nothereanymore. I tend to agree with tfh's point that "the whole thing still seems off".